# Pandas Dataframe grouping columns by column index ranges and get group sums

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, formed of survey responses the column headers are scores and the number row beneath is counts of responses for those values

```
index          |  1  |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5  |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9  | 10 | 11 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business unit  | 100 | 50 | 25 | 50 | 100 | 60 | 80 | 75 | 100 | 50 | 50 |
```

How do I group these columns and retain the counts per the below

```
index          | <=6 | 7=> |
--------------------------------
Business unit  | 385 | 355 |
```

Comment: The dataframe structure is unclear. You say "column headers are scores", but it's labeled as index. What is the orientation of the data? Can you post either pandas output or `df.head().to_dict()` rather than this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` on boolean index (created by comparing column label values with certain value e.g. 7) and use [`GroupBy.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to sum up the columns content values.  Finally, we rename the resulting dataframe column labels, as follows:

```
df.groupby(df.columns >= 7, axis=1).sum().rename({True: '>=7', False: '<=6'}, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
   <=6  >=7
0  385  355
```

**Test Data Preparation:**

```
data = {1: [100], 2: [50], 3: [25], 4: [50], 5: [100], 6: [60], 7: [80], 8: [75], 9: [100], 10: [50], 11: [50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dataframe looks like this:

```
    1   2   3   4    5   6   7   8    9   10  11
0  100  50  25  50  100  60  80  75  100  50  50
```

You can use either `pd.cut` or `np.digitize` to bin your columns and operate on them with `groupby(..., axis=1)` to group horizontally instead of vertically.

Using `pd.cut`

```
bins = pd.cut(df.columns, [0, 6, 11], labels=["<=6", ">=7"])
summary_df = df.groupby(bins, axis=1).sum()

print(summary_df)
   <=6  >=7
0  385  355
```

Using `np.digitize`

```
bins = np.digitize(df.columns, [6], right=True)  # np.digitize is not aware of labels
summary_df = (
    df.groupby(bins, axis=1)
    .sum()
    .rename(columns={0: "<=6", 1: ">=7"})  # add our labels
)

print(summary_df)
   <=6  >=7
0  385  355
```